# Understanding RSA broadcast attack

Tags: python, security, encryption, rsa

I am trying to understand the RSA broadcast attack, and have become quite confused. Maybe someone on here can help me to understand and learn how to solve a problem.
I have been given a message that was encrypted with three individual RSA public keys (N1,N2,N3), resulting in three cypher texts (C1,C2,C3). The public exponent e=3.
I understand from Hastads's broadcast attack that:

c1≡m<sup>3</sup> mod N1,
c2≡m<sup>3</sup> mod N2,
c3≡m<sup>3</sup> mod N3.

Using the Chinese remainder theorem, it should be possible to find a fourth cipher text value C4 that has the following properties:
c4≡c1 mod N1,
c4≡c2 mod N2,
c4≡c3 mod N3,

c4≡m<sup>3</sup> mod (N1 N2 N3)

In theory, I should be able to solve for `m=∛c4`, or (`m=cube root of c4`).
Here is where I'm stuck, and my woeful understanding of math is no help.

Can I simply solve for c4 by letting `c4= C1 mod N1`? Using the values provided to me (actual hex numbers)?  And then use this c4 value in `m=∛c4` equation? This seems way too simple, and I don't think it will produce the correct value. 
Any help is greatly appreciated; I'm trying to solve the problem, but also wish to gain a better understanding of Hastads attack and Chinese remainder theorem. Thank you!

Comment: The point is that m^3 mod N1N2N3 is just m^3, since m must be less than all N_i therefore the m^3 must be less than the N1N2N3.

Answer (score 2):

C4 is already C1 in mod N1. You get nothing from there.

The Hastads attack works for small encryption exponent since the modulus reduction is not performed.

You only need to perform a [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root) root algorithm.